# Hover effect is scrolling the list on a QML GridView

Tags: c++, qt, gridview, scroll, qml

I have a QML GridView with a scrollbar and hover effect, when I move the curso to the page's bottom the hover make an automatic scrolling, I want to stop it. I tried to set the `interactive` property of Flickable to false "`interactive: false`" but it didn't work. How can I stop this behavior?

Obs: When I remove the hover effect the scroll behave in the expected way, just moving through the scrollbar.

```
GridView{
     id: grid
     anchors.margins: 20
     anchors.fill: parent
     cellHeight: 80
     cellWidth: 80
     model: MyModel{}
     highlight: Rectangle {
        color: "lightsteelblue"
        height: parent.cellHeight
        width: parent.cellWidth
        z:2
        opacity: 0.7
     }
     delegate: Column {
            Rectangle {
               color: myColor;
               height: grid.cellHeight * 0.7
               width: grid.cellWidth * 0.7
               border.color: "white"
               anchors.margins: 5
               anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter

               MouseArea {
                   id: mouseRegion
                   anchors.fill: parent
                   hoverEnabled: true
                   onEntered: grid.currentIndex = model.index

               }
          }
          Text { 
             text: name; 
             anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter }
          }
 }
```

Here is the Link to a simple project that reproduces the behavior: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7WUSCDDdwtIbWVDWVFvMjM1djA

Comment: Can you provide a executable code snippet which can be tested??

Comment: Unfortunately it is not possible to provide a executable code, but I can post a code snippet.

Comment: You should read about [**MCVE**](/help/mcve). We can't help you, if we can't replicate your error. Most of us are trying to help you in their free time, which is precious, and guessing around writing code just to find your error is too much to ask. You don't need to share your production code. That would be too much anyway. Just write a complete piece of code, that we can run, in which your situation is condensed. No `TRScrollView` or `FileGridView` (something does not exist on my computer, so... what is it?). If not necessary use a simple `ListModel` rather than the `FileGridView`, e.t.c.

Comment: Because if you can't provide something like this, the probability is high that the answer is *Unfortunately it is not possible to provide an answer.* - See also [point *1.* here](/help/on-topic)

Comment: Folks I am sorry for my code, I was in a hurry and I made a mistake. I forgot that I was using custom components, obviously it would not help. I hope that you can help me yet, I wrote a code from scratch which has the same behavior that my original code. The code can be downloaded by https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7WUSCDDdwtIbWVDWVFvMjM1djA @derM thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

My workmate help me to figured out a solution to my problem. I was using `currentIndex` property to set the hover position in the gridview, as described on documentation this property will smoothly scroll the GridView in the way that the current item becomes visible if the `highlightFollowsCurrentItem`is set to true (default value) and will not scroll if  `highlightFollowsCurrentItem` set to false.
However, after set `highlightFollowsCurrentItem` property to false, the automatic scroll stopped together with my hover effect, which is clearly unwanted. I couldn't figure out what was wrong and we came out with a different approach.
To make the hover work without the automatic scrolling provided by `currentIndex` behavior, we remove it from gridview and used onEntered and onExited to control hover behavior, changing the rectangle visibility (`id:selectedItem`) used to simulate the hover effect as showed below.

```
 GridView{
     id: grid
     anchors.margins: 20
     anchors.fill: parent
     cellHeight: 80
     cellWidth: 80
     model: MyModel{}

     delegate: Item{

           height: grid.cellHeight * 0.9
           width: grid.cellWidth * 0.7

           Rectangle {
               id: selectedItem
               color: "lightsteelblue"
               height: parent.height
               width: parent.width
               z:12
               opacity: 0.7
               visible: false
           }

           Rectangle {
               id:rect
               color: myColor;
               height: parent.height-textName.height
               width: parent.width
               border.color: "white"
               anchors.margins: 5
               anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
               MouseArea {
                   id: mouseRegion
                   anchors.fill: parent
                   hoverEnabled: true
                   onEntered: selectedItem.visible = true
                   onExited: selectedItem.visible = false
                }
           }
           Text {
               id: textName
               text: name;
               anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
               anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
           }
         }
      }
```

It allowed me to avoid automatic scroll and keep the hover effect work properly.